# Write a custom snippet output above the current line in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

Is it possible to write the output of snippet to the line above the current line?
I'm trying to create a snippet where you select an element name from csharp file and it inserts a Summary section above the element.

Snippet:

```
"CSharpSummarySelected": {
    "prefix": "c#-summary-selected",
    "body": [
        "/// <summary>",
        "/// ${1:$TM_SELECTED_TEXT}",
        "/// </summary>",
        "/// <returns>${2:returns}</returns>"
    ],
    "description": "Inserts Summary for component with selected text as name in C# files"
}
```

Comment: I'll write a macro to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can insert a snippet above text without using a macro or an extension - except in the trivial case where the selection was the only thing on the line, which I assume is not the case for you.

Using some macro extension, here [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command), put this into your settings.json:

```
  "multiCommand.commands": [

    {
      "command": "multiCommand.cSharpSummary",
      "sequence": [
        "editor.action.clipboardCopyAction",
        "editor.action.insertLineBefore",
        {
          "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
          "args": {
            "name": "CSharpSummarySelected"
          }
        }

      ]
    }
  ]
```

and your snippet into some snippets file:

```
"CSharpSummarySelected": {
  "prefix": "c#-summary-selected",
  "body": [
      "/// <summary>",
      // "/// ${1:$TM_SELECTED_TEXT}",
      "/// ${1:$CLIPBOARD}",  // this works witheditor.action.clipboardCopyAction, select only

      "/// </summary>",
      "/// <returns>${2:returns}</returns>"
  ],
  "description": "Inserts Summary for component with selected text as name in C# files"
}
```

**NOTE**:  my snippet uses `$CLIPBOARD` instead of `$TM_SELECTED_TEXT`.  This is because the act of inserting a line above your selected text de-selects your selection (i.e., you lose your selection by inserting the line above).

You only have to select your variable, not actually copy it - the macro will take care of the copy action for you.  But the clipBoard will now have your variable on it instead of whatever it had before - this may or may not be acceptable to you - in a macro I think it is unavoidable.

Now the macro will be triggered not with a prefix but with a keybinding.  In keybindings.json:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+alt+b",                      // whatever keybinding you choose
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": { "command": "multiCommand.cSharpSummary" }
},
```

Now when you select some text and trigger the macro with the keybinding your snippet will be inserted above that line with your desired tabstops.  See demo:

[image: demo of macro inserting snippet above current line]

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Visual Studio product includes a code snippet manager.

But with Visual Studio Code, you will need to use an extension.  You will one in the Visual Studio Marketplace [C# Snippets for Visual Studio Code by Jorge Serrano](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jorgeserrano.vscode-csharp-snippets).

[image]

The author has also released the source code on Github https://github.com/J0rgeSerran0/vscode-csharp-snippets. This provide a great learning opportunity for other developer to wrote their extensions.

Comment: I'm creating my own snippets. is what I want possible or do I have to create a custom extension??

Comment: I don't see anything in that extension's documentation that sounds like it will do what you want.  I would love to proved wrong though.